# Page not found getting redirected to local url

Tags: sharepoint-server, publishing-site, custom-masterpage, dns, page-not-found

I have a WebApplcation which contains a Publishing Site with Variations feature enabled. The follwing is and example url for the site "**http://test-server.com/en**"

However when I type a wrong url or an error occurs it takes me to PageNotFound error page but the Url changes to the following "**http://windows-pc:29420/pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx?requestUrl=http://localhost:29420/en/whatsfa**"

I want to Url to point to the following domain name Url is "**http://test-server.com/en**" and not to local Url like "**http://windows-pc:29420/pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx**".

How Do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is PowerShell to set your page not found URL:

```
$spsite = Get-SPSite "Web site URL"
$spsite.filenotfoundurl
$spsite.filenotfoundurl = "/sites/yoursite/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx"
```

Besides, customizing the 404 Redirection in SharePoint for your reference:

https://www.chakkaradeep.com/2009/06/23/customizing-the-404-redirection-in-sharepoint/